# Change Date so all hours are offset by 4 hour

Tags: javascript, date, offset

I want to adjust the `Date` object to always be 4 hours offset. How would I achieve this?

```
var d = new Date();
// d would be 4 hours in the past
```

Comment: You can't, without some really ugly hacking. What is the larger problem you're trying to solve? Besides, changing the behavior of `Date` breaks the documented, existing contract, violates the principle of least astonishment, and a whole bunch of other things that are widely regarded as Good Things.

Comment: `Start -> Control Panel -> Date/Time Settings`

Comment: What are you /actually/ trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
d.setHours(d.getHours()-4);
```

Comment: This changes just the one `Date` instance which — I think — is not what the OP wants.

Comment: I need to make the change for all Date objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
Date.withOffset = function( offset ){
    var r = new Date();
    r.setHours(r.getHours()+offset);
    return r;
};

var d = Date.withOffset( -4 )
// d would be 4 hours in the past
```

You may come up with a better name.

If you wish to break all javascript on your page you may of course use:

```
Date = function () {
    var old = Date;

    function broken() {
        var r = new old();
        r.setHours(r.getHours()-4);
        return r;
    }
    broken.fix = function () {
        Date = old;
    };

    return broken;
}();
```

You can then fix it by calling `Date.fix()`

Comment: I can't modify the system time. I am working a set top box and the time is always in GMT. I need the time to 4 hours in the past for all Date object. I know it's ugly and goes against best practices but this is what I have to do...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a date object with a particular date.  Just subtract the correct milliseconds from the current time and pass that to the date function:

```
var d = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1000*60*60*4);
```

or you can manually set the hours

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours((12 + (d.getHours() - 4))%12)
```

Comment: This changes just the one `Date` instance which — I think — is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL I see what you mean, but this is how it *should* be done.  Working with an instance of a date object.

Comment: I need to modify the Date object. It's ugly but what I have to do to finish the job. Thanks,